# .png issue with foundation orbit slider in IE

Tags: zurb-foundation

Whenever the orbit slider finishes loading, png images and the text appear to have black backgrounds instead of transparancy...

I have tried using !important tags by setting the background and the color properties, but to no avail. Image attached. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your orbit.css change this

```
#featured { 
    background: #000 url('orbit/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

to this

```
#featured { 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('orbit/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; 
}
```